# How can I find a string inside a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, find

I know how to get a string from another string, but only if it's between to things. 
(using PHP)

I have a string like this:

```
a|1904|103489|0234908|
```

The numbers change.

I need to get `103489`

How do I do that?

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) It will split a string by a delimiter.

```
$a = 'a|1904|103489|0234908|';
$parts = explode('|',$a);
echo $parts[2];
```

Comment: This one uses better variable names that the other similar answer. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = 'a|1904|103489|0234908|';
$ret = explode('|', $string);
```

if you need everytime the third element then

```
echo $ret[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos = strpos($mystring, '|' . $findme . '|');

if ($pos !== false) {
    // Not found
}
```

Taken directly from the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Remember to check type, since strpos() will return 0 if the string to search is found at the beginning of the string to search within. This is of course equates to false and will cause you headaches :)

Comment: He does say that he's looking for something between the delimiter; so something like `$pos = strpos($mystring, '|' . $findme . '|');` might be better?

Comment: Just noticed that, good point.

Comment: But that is not what was asked for, “the numbers change”

Comment: How is the code I posted static? In addition, OP didn't give enough information to adapt my code any other way.